# Do we have to delete QUpdSockets?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm programming an application that uses QUdpSockets.
As I'm getting memory problems due to creating sockets with the operator new I would like to know if it is necesary to delete them after closing it.

Code below:

```
socket = new QUdpSocket(this);
socket->bind();
connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(getResponse()));

socket->close();
delete socket; //Do I have to do this to free the mem?
```

Help will be thanked.

Comment: How often are you doing this? You might be better constructing the socket without a parent and then deleting it explicitly as in your code. Otherwise you're not going to delete any memory until the parent object gets destroyed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what `this` is. Whenever that gets destroyed, the `QUdpSocket` will be too.

Comment: Thanks. Now I realized that the sockets deletes correctly as the parent does.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you don't need the socket anymore you can call :

```
socket->deleteLater();
```

And yes, it's better to destroy the socket when you don't need it anymore.

An other solution is to delete 'this', so socket will be also deleted.

Answer (score 0):

If your done with the socket you should delete it. This way you are on the safe side. Also it doesnt hurt. However as it was already pointed out "this" will take for the destruction of the socket (see http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#QObject ).